# Set "read_only_allow_delete" for all Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog

I have Elasticsearch cluster ver 7.10.2 (oss) and i want to set "read_only_allow_delete" setting for all my cluster (not only for some indecies).
How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [run this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#cluster-read-only):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "cluster.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": true
  }
}
```